# My javascript function in the code given below is getting called twice

Tags: javascript, html, function, invocation

The below code is a simple number guessing game.
The function `guess()` is getting called twice.  I am at loss of logic why it's happening.

```
<!DOCTYPTE html>

<html>
    <head><title>Number Guessing Game version 1.0</title></head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="guess();return false;">
        <p><h2>I am your host, human.  I am thinking of a number between 0 and 100, including both</h2></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="inputId" autocomplete="off"></input><button id="submitButton" onclick="guess()">Guess!!</button></p>
        <p><span id="msgId"></span></p>
        <p>Guesses Remaining:<span id="guessId"></span></p>
    </body>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        var doubleRandom = Math.random();
        var guessesLeft = parseInt("10");
        var intRandom = Math.round((doubleRandom*100));
        var spanObj = document.getElementById("msgId");
        var guessObj = document.getElementById("guessId");
        guessObj.innerHTML=guessesLeft;
        function guess()
        {
            var guessedNumber = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
            alert(23);
            if(guessedNumber==null || guessedNumber.trim()==''){
                spanObj.innerHTML="Type something, human";
                return;
            }
            if(isNaN(guessedNumber)){
                spanObj.innerHTML="That better be a number, Human.";
                return;
            }else{
                if(guessedNumber>100){
                    spanObj.innerHTML="That better be a number between 0 and 100, Human.";
                    return;
                }else{
                    spanObj.innerHTML="";
                }
            }
            var accurateAnswer = Math.round(guessedNumber);
            var difference = guessedNumber-intRandom;
            if(difference>45){
                spanObj.innerHTML="That's way too high, Human";
                return;
            }else if(difference<-45){
                spanObj.innerHTML="That's way too low, Human";
            }else if(difference<=45 && difference>0){
                spanObj.innerHTML="That's high, Human";
            }else if(difference>=-45 && difference<0 ){
                spanObj.innerHTML="That's low, Human";
            }else{
                spanObj.innerHTML="Bingo!! You got it!!  Refresh to play agin.";
            }
            if(guessesLeft<=0){
                spanObj.innerHTML="You have exhausted your number of guesses.  Try again.  Refreshing game....";
                setTimeout("location.reload(true)", 3000);
            }
            guessesLeft=guessesLeft-1;
            guessObj.innerHTML=guessesLeft;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout("location.reload(true)", 3000);` Don’t pass strings to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 3000);`

Comment: Thanks @minitech, does that have any performance implications?

Comment: @SidCool Yes - while they may not be noticeable if you only do it once or twice, if you don't break the habit now then you WILL run into problems down the road.

Comment: Another sort of strange thing: `var guessesLeft = parseInt("10");`. Why not just `var guessesLeft = 10;`?

Comment: I get it, changing code accordingly.  Thanks @Kolink.

Comment: @minitech, hmm...you are right there as well, I can directly use the number literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are calling it twice: Once in the button's `onclick` event, and once in the form's `onsubmit` event. Delete one of them.

Comment: Yes, but both are event specific.  If I don't click on the button and simply press enter, why does the onclick event fire?

Comment: Because pressing Enter simulates clicking the primary button of the form.

Comment: @SidCool: `<button>`s submit forms by default. Also, the right event handler to delete is the one on the button.

Comment: Ah, silly of me.  Worked like a charm on removing onclick event for the button.  Thanks @Kolink.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<button id="submitButton" onclick="guess()">Guess!!</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Guess!!" />
```

This way, irrespective of if you click the button, hit enter, or use some other method to submit the form, your event will fire, once.

Answer (score 0):

When you are hit the enter button the form is submitted. On form submit you have the function triggering.

What you could do is to make the button submit the form when clicked.

```
<button onclick="form[0].submit()">guess</button>
```

If the button is clicked the form is submitted, therefore the function in from submission is called on button click. This works on hitting enter as well. Both way the function is triggered only once.

Comment: Why would you do that? The button submits the form by default. The extra `onclick` doesn’t actually do anything.

Comment: Button does not submit the form by default, unless the button is an input element with type submit. Here "sideCool" needs an event to be triggered in button click as well [which is not disclosed here]

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element *“The missing value default is the Submit Button state.”*

Comment: Also, it doesn't have to be an `input` element. `button` elements can have a `type` attribute too.